# Возможно ли при создании SQL таблицы передать ячейкам колонки текущую дату в формате 20171018

Tags: sql, sql-server

Всем привет.

Собственно, вопрос задан выше. Пытался написать что то вроде этого, но, как видите, не то.

```
CREATE TABLE AccountHierarchy_LDR(idExtration int NOT NULL IDENTITY((YEAR(GETDATE()) * 10000 + MONTH(GETDATE()) * 100 + DAY(GETDATE())), 0), idAccountHierarchy varchar(255) NOT NULL, ItemName varchar(255), HierarchyLevel int)
```

Comment: вряд ли identity согласится так работать. она же назначает уникальные номера. А дата в таком формате заведомо не уникальна. можете сделать колонку НЕ identity и назначить ей соответствующий default. И для первичного ключа это очень странное решение, вы действительно хотите что бы в день можно было создать не более одной записи ?

Comment: Да. Но это ведь и не первичный ключ =)

Comment: Это потому, что я не опытный еще :) Добавьте Ваш ответ в "Ответ", отмечу как то, что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно сделать то что вы хотите, если я правильно понял)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTableDate](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [date]  AS (CONVERT([nvarchar],getdate(),(112))),
    [num] [int] NULL
)
```

Пример только для демонстрации создания таблицы со столбцом в нужном формате!

Comment: Почти то, что нужно. Вот так я сделал: 
`CREATE TABLE AccountHierarchy_LDR(idExtraction int NOT NULL DEFAULT (YEAR(GETDATE()) * 10000 + MONTH(GETDATE()) * 100 + DAY(GETDATE())), 
idAccountHierarchy varchar(255) NOT NULL, ItemName varchar(255), HierarchyLevel int)`